# Unable to display Image from source. PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, image

I Had written a previous post about this but since then I have made some changes and attempted other things. I am trying to allow users to upload a profile image to which can be displayed on their profile.

However I am able to get the upload script working, but when trying to display the image I seem to get a image box. I have come to find that the database table updates to the new image and saves it in a folder, then when trying to display that image I am either able to echo out the file name or just a blank image box.

Any help would be much appreciated (Y)

PHP to display image:

```
<?php echo '<img src="', $user_data['profile'], '" alt="', $user_data['name'], '\'s  Profile Image">'; ?>
```

PHP Image upload script (This works and I believe It may be something in the functions script):

```
        <?php
        if (isset($_FILES['profile']) === true) {
            if (empty($_FILES['profile']['name']) === true) {
                ?>
                <p>You have not chosen a image</p>

                <?php

            } else {
                $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');

                $file_name = $_FILES['profile']['name'];
                $file_extension = end((explode('.', $file_name)));
                $file_temp = $_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'];

                if (in_array($file_extension, $allowed) === true) {
                    change_profile_image($session_user_id, $file_temp, $file_extension);
                       header('Location: profile.php?success');
                    exit();

                } else {
                    echo 'Incorrect file type. Allowed: ';
                    echo implode(', ', $allowed);
                }
            }
        }

        if (empty($user_data['profile']) === false) {
            echo '<img class="profileimg" src="', $user_data['profile'], '" alt="', $user_data['name'], '\'s Profile Image">';
        }

        ?>
            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <input type="file" name="profile">
              <div class="submit3">
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="complete"/>
              </div>            
            </form>
```

Functions script:

```
function change_profile_image($user_id, $file_temp, $file_extension) {
  $file_path = 'images/profile/' . substr(md5(time()), 0, 10) . '.' . $file_extension;
  move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path);
  mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `profile` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($file_path) . "'  WHERE `user_id` = " . (int)$user_id);}
```

I believe it has something to do with the functions script but after days of changing the script I still cannot display the image after uploading. PS: Yes I know I should be using MSQLI functions, but I am just trying to finish off a college project to brush up on my PHP knowledge.

Comment: Sidenote: This `mysql_real_escape_string($file_path)` may need to be quoted `mysql_real_escape_string('$file_path')` or `mysql_real_escape_string('".$file_path."')`  unless it's already working for you.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: nope. `'$file_path'` would put `$`, `f`, `i`, etc... into the db. OP's code is correct.

Comment: @MarcB My mistake Marc; I just looked at OP's code again.

Comment: @jsk: did you check the return value of `move_uploaded_file`? Did you check the return value from the `mysql_query` call? None of your code has ANY error handling and simply assumes nothing could ever fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're probably missing quite a bit of info, but you're saving a relative path (`images/profile/...`) in the database, and using that as the `src` of your image. Is the right path as seen from a web client?

To pinpoint the issue, check:

- that the file is indeed saved where it should be
- what the URL to access the image should be
- if you can indeed load the image when accessing that URL directly
- what URL appears in the `<img src>`
- if they match :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found the problem, I had a hatches file in the folder. This was supposed to stop visitors from managing accessing the folder, but was also not allowing the scripts to display the image from the folder.

The file uploaded without issues into the destination folder, and the database/ PHP could locate that image source - but was unable to access it to display.

I hope this helped anyone else who may have the same issue in the future.

Thank you to anyone who contributed to this post.

Answer (score -1):

the image path is likey missing the folder you created to store uploaded images for my case this worked

```
echo '<img src="images/'.$image.'" />';
```

Comment: Could this be the problem? <div class="user"><img class="img_size" src="<?=  $_FILES['image']['name']; ?>" ></div>

Comment: even after doing what you've suggested am unable to. please help